# How can I turn contents of CSV file into XML using Spring batch?

Tags: spring, csv, spring-batch, oxm

I'm using Spring Batch 3.0.8.RELEASE.   I want to read the contents of a CSV file and turn it into XML.  I am familiar with reading CSV files in Spring Batch, but the behavior I've seen is "chunk" oriented processing....one line at a time, and I'm not sure this default behavior will work for me here.

Here is the CSV sample:

```
,WT4RT,AIG-00,694304F,9/1/2017,9/30/2017,"6,975.00",AIG-00201709,10/10/2017,USD,MC
,WT4RT,AIG-00,694317E,9/1/2017,9/30/2017,"2,583.80",AIG-00201709,10/10/2017,USD,MC
,WT4RT,AIG-00,694304G,9/1/2017,9/30/2017,"17,600.00",AIG-00201709,10/10/2017,USD,MC
,WT4RT,AIG-00,694304G,9/1/2017,9/30/2017,740,AIG-00201709,10/10/2017,USD,MC
```

I need to turn this data into the following XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BillingAndCosting version="1.0">
    <ControlArea>
        <SenderId>CMS-BILLING-100</SenderId>
        <WaterMark>92030293829329392030232</WaterMark>
        <RecordCount>2</RecordCount>
        <TimeStamp>2001-12-17T09:30:47-05:00</TimeStamp>
        <DataFileName>String</DataFileName>
    </ControlArea>
    <DataArea>
        <CustomerAccount>
            <ExternalKey>1001</ExternalKey>
            <ExternalSource>HBVenture</ExternalSource>
            <BillingData>
                <ReferenceID>0</ReferenceID>
                <BillingInvoiceNumber>2000016</BillingInvoiceNumber>
                <BillingInvoiceDate>2017-01-31T06:42:07.000Z</BillingInvoiceDate>
                <BillingPeriodFromDate>2017-01-01T06:42:07.000Z</BillingPeriodFromDate>
                <BillingPeriodThruDate>2017-01-31T06:42:07.000Z</BillingPeriodThruDate>
                <BillingInvoiceType>NEW</BillingInvoiceType>
                <BillingAmount CurrencyID="USD">1290.39</BillingAmount>
                <InvoiceItem>
                    <CategoryCode>res-group</CategoryCode>
                    <TaxCategoryID>C2</TaxCategoryID>
                    <InvoiceItemAmount CurrencyID="USD">1290.39</InvoiceItemAmount>
                    <ProductID>694601F</ProductID>
                    <ISVUID>1</ISVUID>
                </InvoiceItem>
            </BillingData>
            <BillingData>
                <ReferenceID>0</ReferenceID>
                <BillingInvoiceNumber>2000017</BillingInvoiceNumber>
                <BillingInvoiceDate>2017-01-31T06:42:07.000Z</BillingInvoiceDate>
                <BillingPeriodFromDate>2017-01-01T06:42:07.000Z</BillingPeriodFromDate>
                <BillingPeriodThruDate>2017-01-31T06:42:07.000Z</BillingPeriodThruDate>
                <BillingInvoiceType>NEW</BillingInvoiceType>
                <BillingAmount CurrencyID="USD">590.39</BillingAmount>
                <InvoiceItem>
                    <CategoryCode>gateway_resource_group</CategoryCode>
                    <TaxCategoryID>C2</TaxCategoryID>
                    <InvoiceItemAmount CurrencyID="USD">590.39</InvoiceItemAmount>
                    <ProductID>694601F</ProductID>
                    <ISVUID>1</ISVUID>
                </InvoiceItem>
            </BillingData>
```

I'm showing only a portion of the XML for brevity.   The thing I don't know is:  how to use Spring Batch to read the entire CSV file to populate an Object that I can then send to the XML Marshaller for converting into XML.

Can it be done with Spring batch, or do I have to 'roll my own'?

Answer (score 0):

We use `StaxEventItemWriter` as ItemWriter (example below)

```
<bean id = "xmlItemWriter" 
      class = "org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter"> 
      <property name = "resource" value = "file:my_path_to_xml.xml" /> 
      <property name = "marshaller" ref = "reportMarshaller" /> 
      <property name = "rootTagName" value = "BillingAndCosting" /> 
   </bean>  

   <bean id = "reportMarshaller" 
      class = "org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
      <property name = "classesToBeBound"> 
         <list> 
            <value>BillingAndCosting</value> 
         </list> 
      </property> 
   </bean>
```

Comment: I'm not sure my explanation is coming across clearly - yes, I could use the StaxEventItemWriter with Jaxb2Marshaller, but in order to fully assemble the BillingAndCosting object I have to read through the entire CSV file and only at the very end call the xmltemWriter to gen the XML from it....   and I don't know how to do that with Spring Batch which wants to read-write-read-write-read-write... one record at a time...

Answer (score 0):

You can use *FlatFileItemReader* for reading the CSV file. Follow the below sample code:

**ItemReader reads a complete line one by one from input csv file. FlatFileItemReader is used for reading the csv file.**

```
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <!-- Mapper which maps each individual items in a record to properties in POJO -->
                <bean class="com.websystique.springbatch.ExamResultFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>

            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <!-- A tokenizer class to be used when items in input record are separated by specific characters -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
                </bean>
            </property>

        </bean>

    </property>

</bean>
```

**XML ItemWriter which writes the data in XML format.**

```
<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/examResult.xml" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="UniversityExamResultList" />
    <property name="marshaller">
        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
            <property name="classesToBeBound">
                <list>
                    <value>com.websystique.springbatch.model.ExamResult</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**You should also go through the official Spring docs [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html)**

Comment: Yes - I can use the FlatFileItemReader to read the CSV and StaxEventItemWriter to write the XML out.... trouble is that I cannot read one record, write one record out.... read another write another. If you look at the XML, the BillingAndCosting structure has a nested hierarchy. There are (N) Customer objects each one with (N) Billing Data objects and each one of those can have (N) InvoiceItems. What I have to do is to read one line at a time and in the Processor tuck that data into the appropriate Business Object or Objects that each CSV line represents.

Comment: I can do all that, but when do I send this entire structure to the XML Writer - presumably when the entire BillingAndCosting structure is fully populated with all the data, so how will I know what the last CSV Line is, so I can finally return the fully populated BillingAndCosting data structure to the writer?

Comment: The problem for me is the timing control - how to tell that there is no more data coming so I can send it for XML Marshalling and Writing.

Comment: First of all, update the complete CSV data and the XML sample. I will be able to help you after seeing the complete information.
The best way to deal with this kind of scenario is to read everything from the CSV file using the ItemReader and pass the params to ItemProcessor.
ItemProcessor when working with step processing makes sure that you're processing 1 record at a time and the processor know when the last record is processed.

Read more about this in Spring documentation.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemProcessor